# How to add type and search for Magento2 Products Attributes (dropdown)?

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.3.3

> #### I  want to add "type and search" select box feature in Magento 2 product attribute dropdown.

It is very difficult to select brand when i have more than 1000 brands .

[image]

**can anyone help me ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using the following guide.

Please follow the below guide this guide will help you to create a dropdown attribute as you want.

https://webkul.com/blog/add-ui-select-with-search-filter-admin-form-magento2/

hope this will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: I think we had conversation on this to them , Im trying to modify webkul's marketplace plugin as this become hassle when you have more than 200 seller.

Comment: @NafeesKhabir Thanks, it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

can't build a PoC for this yet, but something to bake later.

For now my thoughts are, you can utilize https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ as custom implementation for your work, with mixins may be.

Or something existing from magento ui - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_quickSearch.html

Comment: Im trying to implement it in product upload page